# In R Tidymodels: Apply separate pca (PreProcessing/Recipes) to different dataframes and then merge them for training

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I want to use the tidymodels framework, where three different dataframes separately are Preprocessed using pca; and then I would like the PCA-components from the three dataframes to be put together in one training. For the training I would like to use ridge regression applying cross-validation. It is further important to *avoid data leakage* of the PCAs; so that the PCAs should be implemented *within* the cross-validation procedure rather than separately be carried out before. (So df_x1, df_x2, df_x3 in the example code below should create their own PCA-componenets, where these components should be predictors in ONE final ridge regression predicting y.

This is some example data:

```
set.seed(42)
df_x1 <- tibble(V1=runif(10, 1, 10), V2=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x2 <- tibble(V3=runif(10, 1, 10), V4=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x3 <- tibble(V5=runif(10, 1, 10), V6=runif(10, 1, 10))

y <- runif(10, 1, 10)

df_x1 <- cbind(df_x1, y)
df_x2 <- cbind(df_x2, y)
df_x3 <- cbind(df_x3, y)
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
library(recipes)
library(workflows)
library(parsnip)
library(tune)


df_x1_recipe <-
  recipe(y ~ .,
         data = df_x1) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_pca(all_predictors(), threshold = .95)

df_x2_recipe <-
  recipe(y ~ .,
                  data = df_x2) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_pca(all_predictors(), threshold = .95)

df_x3_recipe <-
  recipe(y ~ .,
                  data = df_x3) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_pca(all_predictors(), threshold = .95)


# Cross-validation: In order to avoid data leakage I reckon the three recpies above should have the same folds.
cv_splits <- vfold_cv(df_x3, v = 2, repeats = 1, strata = NULL) # , ... ,  breaks = 4
cv_splits

# Model
dfx1_x3_model <-
  linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

# Tuning
dfx1_x3_grid <- expand.grid(
  penalty = 10 ^ seq(-3, -1, length = 5),
  mixture = (0:4) / 4
)

control <- control_grid(save_pred = TRUE)


dfx1_x3_tune <- tune_grid(
  c(df_x1_recipe, df_x2_recipe, df_x3_recipe),
  model = df3_model,
  resamples = df3_cv_splits,
  grid = df3_glmn_grid,
  control = ctrl
)
```

Comment: Hi! I have one question. What do you mean by: "I would like the PCA-components from the three data frames to be put together in one training"? You would like to `rbinding` the PCA-components while the `y` variable is simply repeated 3 times?

Comment: Hi, df_x1, df_x2, df_x3 should create their own PCA-componenets (e.g., df_x1_1componenet, df_x2_2componenet, df_x3_1componenet). These components I would like to go in as predictors in ONE final ridge regression in order to predict y. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that the following code answers your question but it should correspond to the procedure you described. I added a few comments that should explain the code.

```r
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(recipes)
library(parsnip)
library(tune)
library(rsample)

# data
set.seed(42)
df_x1 <- tibble(V1=runif(10, 1, 10), V2=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x2 <- tibble(V3=runif(10, 1, 10), V4=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x3 <- tibble(V5=runif(10, 1, 10), V6=runif(10, 1, 10))

y <- runif(10, 1, 10)

# run PCA
my_PCA <- function(data) {
  pca_repice <- recipe(~ ., data = {{data}}) %>% 
    step_center(all_predictors()) %>% 
    step_scale(all_predictors()) %>% 
    step_pca(all_predictors(), threshold = 0.95)

  extract_PC <- juice(prep(pca_repice))
  extract_PC
}

cbind_PCA <- map_dfc(list(df_x1, df_x2, df_x3), my_PCA)
cbind_PCA$y <- y
```

This is the result cbinding the results of applying `my_PCA()` to `df_x1`, ..., `df_x3`

```r
cbind_PCA
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#>       PC1    PC2    PC11    PC21   PC12   PC22     y
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 -0.442  1.07  -1.04    0.143  -0.834  0.301  7.08
#>  2 -1.13   0.510  0.378  -1.58   -0.671  0.213  9.85
#>  3  0.130 -1.77  -0.497   1.04   -1.42   1.25   7.84
#>  4  0.270  1.33  -1.02    0.339   1.77   0.250  6.10
#>  5  0.290  0.319  2.16   -0.0329 -1.55  -0.649  8.65
#>  6 -0.516 -1.15  -0.439  -0.854   1.64   0.184  2.71
#>  7 -1.20  -0.653  1.52    0.592   1.28   0.138  3.44
#>  8  2.49  -0.237  0.0456  1.24   -0.711 -0.740  8.45
#>  9  0.218  0.331 -0.452  -1.14    0.284 -1.23   7.24
#> 10 -0.116  0.258 -0.644   0.262   0.214  0.278  3.16
```

Now I just follow the code you defined in the question

```
# define the new recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(y ~ ., data = cbind_PCA)

# define the model
my_model <- linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

# define the tuning grid
my_grid <- expand.grid(
  penalty = 10 ^ seq(-3, -1, length = 5),
  mixture = (0:4) / 4
)

# define the CV splits
my_cv_splits <- vfold_cv(cbind_PCA, v = 2, repeats = 1)
```

and this is the result

```
# train the model
my_result <- tune_grid(
  object = my_recipe, 
  model = my_model, 
  resamples = my_cv_splits, 
  grid = my_grid, 
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE)
)

# view results
collect_predictions(my_result)
#> # A tibble: 250 x 6
#>    id    .pred  .row penalty mixture     y
#>    <chr> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Fold1  6.21     2 0.001         0  9.85
#>  2 Fold1  6.21     2 0.00316       0  9.85
#>  3 Fold1  6.21     2 0.01          0  9.85
#>  4 Fold1  6.21     2 0.0316        0  9.85
#>  5 Fold1  6.63     4 0.001         0  6.10
#>  6 Fold1  6.63     4 0.00316       0  6.10
#>  7 Fold1  6.63     4 0.01          0  6.10
#>  8 Fold1  6.63     4 0.0316        0  6.10
#>  9 Fold1  6.15     7 0.001         0  3.44
#> 10 Fold1  6.15     7 0.00316       0  3.44
#> # ... with 240 more rows
collect_metrics(my_result)
#> # A tibble: 50 x 7
#>    penalty mixture .metric .estimator   mean     n std_err
#>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
#>  1   0.001    0    rmse    standard   2.23       2  0.342 
#>  2   0.001    0    rsq     standard   0.182      2  0.0792
#>  3   0.001    0.25 rmse    standard   6.72       2  2.40  
#>  4   0.001    0.25 rsq     standard   0.0916     2  0.0626
#>  5   0.001    0.5  rmse    standard   7.16       2  3.07  
#>  6   0.001    0.5  rsq     standard   0.103      2  0.0830
#>  7   0.001    0.75 rmse    standard   7.24       2  3.15  
#>  8   0.001    0.75 rsq     standard   0.104      2  0.0825
#>  9   0.001    1    rmse    standard   7.27       2  3.19  
#> 10   0.001    1    rsq     standard   0.104      2  0.0824
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

## EDIT: Modify recipe to avoid data leakage

I modified the definition of the recipe to merge all the PCA steps into a single recipe, and now it should avoid the data leakage that you mentioned.

```r
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(recipes)
library(parsnip)
library(tune)
library(rsample)

# data
set.seed(42)
df_x1 <- tibble(V1=runif(10, 1, 10), V2=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x2 <- tibble(V3=runif(10, 1, 10), V4=runif(10, 1, 10))
df_x3 <- tibble(V5=runif(10, 1, 10), V6=runif(10, 1, 10))

y <- runif(10, 1, 10)
my_data <- cbind(y, df_x1, df_x2, df_x3)

# define the recipe
my_recipe <- recipe(y ~ ., data = my_data) %>% 
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_scale(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_pca(V1, V2, threshold = 0.95, prefix = "group1_") %>% 
  step_pca(V3, V4, threshold = 0.95, prefix = "group2_") %>% 
  step_pca(V5, V6, threshold = 0.95, prefix = "group3_")
```

The rest of the code is more or less the same as before.

```r
# define the model
my_model <- linear_reg(penalty = tune(), mixture = tune()) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

# define the tuning grid
my_grid <- expand.grid(
  penalty = 10 ^ seq(-3, -1, length = 5),
  mixture = (0:4) / 4
)

# define the CV splits
my_cv_splits <- vfold_cv(my_data, v = 2, repeats = 1)

# train the model
my_result <- tune_grid(
  object = my_recipe, 
  model = my_model, 
  resamples = my_cv_splits, 
  grid = my_grid, 
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I'm not super familiar with *tidymodels* and all the packages in that environment so probably this is not the ideal solution, but I think that the procedure does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for this; but as I understand the code there are now data leakage as the PCAs are made before the cross-validation folds as opposed to within the folds, right? That is, the PCA is build with all data (although some should be separate for the "testing" part of the cross-validation procedure, or?

Comment: Please note that I have now added some about this in the descriptions.

Comment: Hi! I added an edit to the previous post with a few more comments. If that answers your objection on data leakage (and you are right on that point, IMO), then I will delete the previous answer.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help: much appreciated! and thanks for having upvoting my question :)

Comment: please note that the bounty will be released in 19 hours :)